# Office 365 document Library ItemAdded event is not firing

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, csom, remote-event-receiver

Event is attached to document library, but it is not firing when I upload document. Below is the `Element.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="## Heading ##http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Receivers ListTemplateId="101">
    <Receiver>
      <Name>DocumentEventReceiverItemAdded</Name>
      <Type>ItemAdded</Type>
      <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      <Url>~remoteAppUrl/Services/DocumentEventReceiver.svc</Url>
    </Receiver>
    <Receiver>
      <Name>DocumentEventReceiverItemAdding</Name>
      <Type>ItemAdding</Type>
      <Url>~remoteAppUrl/Services/DocumentEventReceiver.svc</Url>
      <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
    </Receiver>
  </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

ItemAdded Code:

```
if (properties.EventType == SPRemoteEventType.ItemAdded)
{
    using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties))
    {
        if (clientContext != null)
        {
            try
            {
                List lstDemoeventReceiver = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(properties.ItemEventProperties.ListTitle);
                ListItem itemDemoventReceiver = lstDemoeventReceiver.GetItemById(properties.ItemEventProperties.ListItemId);
                itemDemoventReceiver["testname"] = " Event fired.";
                itemDemoventReceiver.Update();
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The remote event receiver is attached to app/add-in web lists/libraries as per my knowledge, if you want to attache remote ER to host web lists/libraries.you need register it manually.

Sample Code:

```
private void AppInstalledMethod(SPRemoteEventProperties _properties)
        {
            using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateAppEventClientContext(_properties, false))
            {
                if (clientContext != null)
                {
                    Web web = clientContext.Web;
                    var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Doc4");
                    clientContext.Load(web);
                    clientContext.Load(list);
                    clientContext.Load(list.EventReceivers);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation receiver = new EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation();
                    receiver.EventType = EventReceiverType.ItemAdded;
                    OperationContext op = OperationContext.Current;
                    Message msg = op.RequestContext.RequestMessage;
                    receiver.ReceiverUrl = msg.Headers.To.ToString();
                    receiver.ReceiverName = "ItemAdded";
                    receiver.Synchronization = EventReceiverSynchronization.Synchronous;
                    receiver.SequenceNumber = 5000;
                    //adding receiver the host web.
                    // we are adding event receiver to site context so that event receriver fires for sub-sub-sites
                    list.EventReceivers.Add(receiver);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();                   
                }
            }
        }
```